# Ajax fetches data and loads menu from javaScript only after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('#subregionListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event){


    var output = $('#subregions');
    var region = getUrlVars()["reg"];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/my/getsubregions.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        data: {reg: region},
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            var out = '';
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                out += '<li><a href="subregions.html">' + item.subregion.capitalize() + '</a></li>';
            });

            output.append(out);
            output.trigger('create');
            output.listview('refresh');

        },

        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
});

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

So the problem with this code is that it creates list not after page is initially loaded, but after it is loaded and refreshed, I have tried many things but none of them worked.
Also, this is html code from where the script is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="subregionListPage" data-role="page">
    <script src="getsubregions2.js"></script>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Select Sub Region</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
         <ul id='subregions' data-role="listview"></ul>
    </div>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Updated code after suggestion:

```
    $(document).on('pagecreate', '#subregionListPage', function(event){

    var output = $('#subregions');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/my/getsubregions.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        data: {reg: $.urlParam('reg')},
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){        
            var out = '';
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                out += '<li><a href="subregions.html">' + item.subregion.capitalize() + '</a></li>';
            });


            output.append(out);
            output.trigger('create');
            output.listview('refresh');

        },

        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
});

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what exactly is happening your code:

### Scenario

- The first time when you load your page, the element `#subregionListPage` doesn't so far exist in the DOM. And attaching a handler for the `pageinit` event on the element is done way before that element was ever rendered.
- The next time you reload the page, and since the event handler was previously attached to the `pageinit` event on `#subregionListPage`, the handler gets fired.

Quoting from [jQuery's docs regarding `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements ***must exist*** at the point the call to .bind() occurs.

The `.bind()` is an older method in jQuery's implementation (added in version 1.0). It is not as flexible as the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method because, using the `.on()` you can attach event handlers to *elements that currently don't even exist in the DOM*.

This is possible by attaching event handlers to a super-parent (e.g. the `document`), and when a particular child element fires an event, the event propagates (*bubbles*) up to that parent. Eventually, event handlers attached to the parent in the context of the child will get fired when the event reaches it.

### Solution

Substitute your `.bind()` with `on()` as such:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#subregionListPage', function(event){
   /* ... */
}
```

**Note:** The `pageinit` event has been deprecated as of jQuery v1.4. The recommended event to use in this case is `pagecreate`.

---

### Update

As pointed, you have the script where you are binding the `pagecreate` event, inside the `div` that is has to trigger it upon creation:

```
<div id="subregionListPage" data-role="page">
     <script src="getsubregions2.js"></script>
     <!-- rest of your HTML -->
```

What happens here is that on the *inital* loading of your HTML, the div `#subregionListPage` exists, but the event binding for it doesn't - because the Javascript code needed for this is not run yet and there is no handler registered to capture `pagecreate` event fired by it.

Move the script to your HTML's `<head>`, so that your JS is ready at the first load of your page to bind that particular handler for `#subregionListPage`.

Comment: Thanks for a brief answer, it seems that it works well and triggers success and outputs what ever there is, the problem remains that menus isn't loaded. When I debug it using chrome, I can see that PHP function that is supposed to fetch data, fetches it only after reload of the page, on initial load it returns No Properties. Any ideas why it is the case ? I figured out that on first load it does not assign anything to region parameter, so it doesn't return anything, but on second reload it assigns.

Comment: Do you load your menus with the same approach, I mean via AJAX?

Comment: Yeah, ajax returns array ant then I make listview, maybe it doesn't get url parameter after first load ?

Comment: _When I debug it using chrome, I can see that PHP function that is supposed to fetch data, fetches it only after reload of the page_ - make sure you have applied the binding using `.on()` (as pointed in the answer). Do you have a `$(document).ready()` handler or the equivalent `$(function(){ ... });` to make sure your script runs once the DOM is ready?

Comment: I updated post with updates that were made according to your suggestion

Comment: Yes, it is, there is one other similar code that fetches regions and then when you select region it goes to this html with url variable. The funny thing is that regions loads up as intended, but subregions doesn't, the only difference between two codes is url variable handling.

Comment: @marty, check the _update_, I think I found what was causing your code to run only when it was refreshed soon after being loaded. Meanwhile, in your `$.each()`, change `out += 'li html';` to `output.append('li html')` and remove the `output.append(out)` after the loop or otherwise you'll end up with duplicate `li`s.

Comment: It isn't a problem, I tested two identical files that initially worked fine, data would be loaded after initial load, but suddenly it would get loaded after refresh when I would pass parameters to php file and do binding in php file, I haven't figured out how to fix it yet

Comment: _data would be loaded after initial load, but suddenly it would get loaded after refresh_ ... Have you taken note of the `pagecreate` event in the docs that it is fired _only once per page load_?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put the code in $(document).ready(function(){}) if yes then try to put alert after success function see if the alert works on page load.